# Need Port redirection pattern for IIS Windows

Tags: asp.net-mvc, node.js, iis, web-config

I have an application running under `http://localhost/TestApp` inside that I'm making an AJAX call to my Node.js app running under port 3000 i.e. `http://localhost:3000`

Now I want to configure my IIS whenever a request comes as `http://localhost/Node` just wanted to redirect to `http://localhost:3000/` for example: If I make a request to URL `http://localhost/Node/Sample` I want it to be handled by my server to redirect the request to `http://localhost:3000/Sample`

I tried with .NET installer URL Rewrite and tried to config some pattern but it didn't work for me. Could you guys please help me out?

### My Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>This is an Index page</h2>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Node/sample",
            success: function () {
                alert('Done');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Error I'm getting is below..

[URL Redirection not happening and throws resource not found exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiYC7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="RedirectTo3000" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="/Node/(.*)" />          
      <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="/Node/([a-z]+)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost:3000/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This should work...

Comment: Thanks for your help. The above solution is redirect all my request from http://localhost to http://localhost:3000. But I need to support only for particular pattern "http://localhost/Node" to "http://localhost:3000".

Comment: I used <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="RedirectTo3000" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*\/Node.*" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost:3000/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite> But still the required redirection is not happening. Even I cleared browser cache still the problem exists. Its showing "The resource cannot be found. " exception. Think it expecting virtual file/folder but its an endpoint which i'm trying to redirect. Is that the problem?

Comment: Have revised answer. Please try that once and check if that works.

Comment: Have you checked? Is this working? If yes then please mark the answer as expected. Thanks.

Comment: HI Kiran, I checked but still I'm getting "The resource cannot be found" exception. Not sure whether it looks for virtual folder/File.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for update. Can you please share the screenshots of error for reference? Let me see if I can help after reviewing those.

Comment: Hi Kiran, I have updated my question and attached the screenshot of the same. Could you please check and reply back? Apologies for the delay..

Comment: Thanks. Can you please share the screen shot from your IS?